# How do i access an array object inside a function in ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have an array object passed to my ejs file (front end) from NodeJS backend code. I need to access this array object inside a function which is called on click of a button in my ejs file. Could you please let me know how do I access the array object inside the function.

I am passing the array object data from NodeJS (in app.js) to my ejs file (gallery.ejs) like this:

```js
res.render("gallery",{data:billdata})
```

I am able to access the array object 'data' in `gallery.ejs`. For example i can access an element of array object 'data' in `gallery.ejs` like this:

```
<%data._embedded.tickets[0].totals.sub_total%>
```

Now I want 'data' to be accessed inside a function defined in `gallery.ejs` , the function is called on click of a button. I want to pass the 'data' object to the function myFunction below so that the object can be accessed from within the function. How do I do that?

```html
<button type="button" id="zero_perc" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="myFunction()">0%</button>
```

I am not sure how to pass the array object 'data' to the function `myFunction()` . Any pointers or code samples will be very helpful.

Comment: a code sample would be very helpful

Comment: ejs file is not send to client. EJS is converted to html and then it is sent to browser. Do you want to send some data along with rendered html to browser so that js can access that data?

Comment: indolentdeveloper- I have updated the issue description to give some more detail.. hope it clarifies your question

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction() {
    for(var i in arguments) {
        console.log(arguments[i]); // U can access all objects here
    }
}
var params = [10, 15];
myFunction(...params);

// It could be called using array of objects
//var params = [{a:1}, {b:1}];
//myFunction(...params);
```